# Extract json from given child data mysql

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I have a JSON stored in my table column data_analytics, I want to extract the type and its user where the user has a matching timestamp;

for example, if my timestamp is "12-07-2022" I should get the result as

Expected result

```
{
  type1: {
    user1: {
      timestamp: ["12-07-2022", "15-07-2022"],
    },
  },

  type2: {
    user2: {
      time: 4,
      timestamp: ["11-07-2022", "12-07-2022"],
    },
  },
}
```

Original json

```
    {
                type1: {
                    user1: {
                      timestamp: ["12-07-2022", "15-07-2022"],
                    },
                  },
                type2: {
                    user2: {
                      time: 4,
                      timestamp: ["11-07-2022", "12-07-2022"],
                    },
                    user6: {
                      time: 4,
                      timestamp: ["10-07-2022", "19-07-2022", "15-07-2022"],
                    },
                  },
                type3: {
                    user3: {
                      time: 4,
                      timestamp: ["10-07-2022", "19-07-2022", "15-07-2022"],
                    },
                    user2: {
                      time: 2,
                      timestamp: ["11-07-2022", "14-07-2022"],
                    },
                  },
    }
```

Comment: is the original json in one record row or in multiple rows?

Comment: its in one record but i want this to perform for all the rows as well

Comment: That's not valid JSON at all, so none of the builtin JSON functions in MySQL will work on it. So you'll have to fetch the whole "document" into some client application, and parse it there. You can't do it in SQL if the JSON is not valid.

Comment: thanks bill, can you suggest me what approch i need to follow to achive this result

Comment: I did suggest an approach in my previous comment.